# Return loss at the input of two cascaded microwave systems

Tags: reflection

How can we calculate the **return loss at the input of the Integrated system** which has two microwave sub-systems of return loss $10dB$ & $20dB$ respectively cascaded together?

**My Approach**:
We know: $$RL=-20 \times log_{10}|\Gamma|$$ where $\Gamma$ is the reflection coefficient
$A.T.P \rightarrow$ 
[image]
$$Given: \quad |\Gamma_A| \quad (in \quad dB)=10 \quad and \quad |\Gamma_B| \quad (in \quad dB)=20 $$
$$\implies |\Gamma_A|=0.32 \quad and \quad |\Gamma_B|=0.1$$
Now how can i proceed?? Any hints or suggestions please....?

Comment: Would you like to migrate this to the electrical engineering stackexchange?

Comment: Do you know the other  s-parameters of the two blocks? And of the load on the output of block B?

Comment: @ The Photon no i don't know anything more about the given microwave system

Comment: @The Photon - In my opinion, this question relates to S-parameters and belongs to problems arising in experimental physics. It needs not to be moved to EE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have enough information to answer the question.

You need the full S-parameters for the two two-ports (or at least for 2-port 'A', if you know the output of 2-port 'B' is perfectly terminated).

The reason is that the signal that will reflect back from 2-port 'B' must first pass through 2-port 'A' forwards and then backwards before it is seen at the input port. There will also be signals that reflect multiple times between the output of 2-port 'A' and the input of 2-port 'B' before returning to the input.

Overall, the reflected signal will be something like

$$a_{in}\left(S_{11}^A + S_{21}^A S_{11}^B S_{12}^A + S_{21}^A S_{11}^B S_{22}^A S_{11}^B S_{12}^A + \ldots\right)$$

where $a_{in}$ is the input signal, and $S_{xx}^Y$ represents the $xx$ S-parameter of 2-port $Y$.

If 2-port 'B' is not perfectly terminated, you also have to consider signals that pass through both 2-ports before finally reflecting back from the end termination.

In practice, once you do have the required information, this can be solved a few different ways

- Recognize the geometric series in the expression for the reflection and simplify the expression using the known results for a geometric series.
- Transform the 2-port descriptions from S-parameters to another representation that simplifies the expression (such as T-parameters).
- Know in advance that some of the terms are negligible. For example, the reverse isolation term ($S_{12}$) of 2-port 'A' might be very small if 'A' is an amplifier, in which case the whole expression becomes simply $S_{11}^A$. Or $S_{22}^A$ might be very small if 'A' is a length of cable, allowing you to eliminate all but the first two terms in the reflection expression.